# Firebase disable automatic login account creation

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building a web and mobile app using firebase. When signing with Google, firebase auto creates a new account in the project (Auth) if one does not exist. Its fine with the mobile app.

But with the web, I just want existing users (who created accounts with mobile app) to signin and not create new accounts via web.

How do I setup firebase not to create new accounts if one does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to restrict social sign-in with Firebase Auth to "only sign in, not sign up".

If you have a means of detecting users that have signed in using the app at some point (e.g. by writing a value to your database in a specific location), you could check for that value when signing in via the web, and, if missing, display a screen encouraging users to install the mobile app.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

> [Link Multiple Auth Providers to an Account Using
>   JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking)
>
> You can allow users to sign in to your app using multiple
>   authentication providers by linking auth provider credentials to an
>   existing user account. Users are identifiable by the same Firebase
>   user ID regardless of the authentication provider they used to sign
>   in. For example, a user who signed in with a password can link a
>   Google account and sign in with either method in the future. Or, an
>   anonymous user can link a Facebook account and then, later, sign in
>   with Facebook to continue using your app.